# Does MSBuild 2010 /t:Package switch package an existing DLL or build it first?

Tags: solution-package, build

Does MSBuild 2010 /t:Package switch package an existing SharePoint WebPart or build it first?

In other words can I do the following:

```
MSBuild /p:Configuration=Release /m MyWebPart.csproj
Then do something else like ILMerge and sign
MSBuild /p:Configuration=Release /m MyWebPart.csproj /t:Package
```

To package the ILMerged and signed Webpart to a WSP?